# Web server for Objective-C 

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa, macos

How can I create a webserver from my Obj-C app, and post custom HTML to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your could improve your question by making it more specific. What, exactly, are you having trouble with? Broad, open-ended, "how do I build an airplane?" type questions show little effort on your part and require much more effort to answer well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check:
[SimpleHTTPServer](http://culturedcode.com/cocoa/)
[CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)

Answer (score 6):

To embed a lightweight HTTP server in iOS or Mac apps, check out [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) which has a modern and clean architecture designed on top of Grand Central Dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

It would most likely be easier and far more secure to use something like FastCGI and then use an existing HTTP server such as Nginx to serve the HTML that your app passes along rather than trying to embed an HTTP server directly in your application. Plus Nginx is extremely fast and can handle huge server traffic without really breaking a sweat which not all other HTTP servers can say.

Plus using an embedded server means that your app and your HTTP server must run under the same UID which is bad from a security perspective as anyone compromising the HTTP server gains access to all your website files as well.

Comment: What Simon said.... rolling your own or embedding an HTTP server in your app is an **awesome** way to open up numerous security holes.

Comment: Could you please explain why implementing a HTTP server like CocoaHTTP (2nd link above) where you have full control over valid requests and the responses does open security holes? Can't see that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested too knowing what security holes are in the CocoaHTTP.

Comment: @Christian Beer Having full control of requests and responses is irrelevant. You have full control over the requests and responses in any HTTP application. The problem with baking in the HTTP processing into your application code is that if there is a bug in the HTTP processing code then there is no barrier between the HTTP server and your application. If using Apache or Nginx with your app via FastCGI and both are running under different users then if a hacker compromises Apache or Nginx there will be an extra barrier that they must surmount. Continued below.

Comment: @Christian Beer So as I was saying having full control of the requests and responses has no meaning because in order for your code to have access to said requests and responses the HTTP server must process them and provide them to you in some form. This processing is where the likely bugs and security holes can occur, it only takes a buffer overflow or some such for an attacker to modify the behaviour of the HTTP server which is embedded within your app. This all happens before the request ever reaches your application.

Comment: @Cromulent That's not a problem specific to an HTTP Server. Using a library that has an exploitable bug, or not validating user input sufficiently can happen in any application.

Comment: @amiuhle Sure but I tailored my point to the discussion in question.

Comment: the extra barrier is present should one use the provided servers written in obj-c language as a httpd server. embedding looks like a fork in the conversation. of course, your points worth noting for those considered that case.